# Data on Individual Performance of Franchises

Tags: data-request

I am doing a research project on the effect of market sharing agreements on the profits of franchises, and I would like to get some empirical data to guide my analysis. Are large franchises required to publish data on the individual performance of their franchisees? I looked on the McDonald's website, and found a huge amount of legal information, but I am not sure which documents, if any, are relevant to me. What would be the best place to look for this kind of data? I would like anything possible, but especially data on sales, profits, etc. over time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how detailed you your data want, but in the case of McDonald's or Wendy's, you can find some data in their annual reports. They split their total revenues and costs into company-operated and franchised restaurants.

Hope that helps you